# How to use Drush or Migrate module to create/edit/delete nodes hourly

Tags: drush, migrations

I need to

- Create new nodes (W/12 fields) hourly from a new table/fields in the Drupal DB (x_table).
- Update currently created nodes via current x_table rows.
- Delete nodes once the row has been removed from x_table.

My skill sets do not include coding, and for years I have gotten by with the great Drupal modules, although I haven't had to import/update/delete rotating 10,000+ nodes.  I previously used Feeds w/out updating, and it was extremely slow.

I've been reading I should be using the Migrate module and/or Drush.  (I understand that Drush is part of Migrate)??  Anyhow I have installed the migrate module, but I have been completely baffled for an hour by their UI.  It seems I need to create some data/text files for it to work, which is why I was trying to use the UI.

I feel that it will likely be best to create these scripts using Drush and calling them hourly via cron.

My question is, how do I create the script??  I'm not quite sure how to map the fields either?  Could someone suggest a page showing this, or put together a quick example to work off of?  30 mn's of using the search engine hasn't shown me much, mostly only using csv files, etc. and not pulling from a database.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

In your module for the migration use this code:

```
function YOURMODULENAME_cron() {
$machine_name = "MACHINE NAME OF YOUR MIGRATION";
$last_run = variable_get('YOURMODULENAME_last_cron', 0);
$interval = variable_get('YOURMODULENAME_cron_interval', 60);//60 seconds
if(time() - $last_run > $interval)
  {
   variable_set('YOURMODULENAME_last_cron', time());//track the last_run time
   $migration = Migration::getInstance($machine_name);
   $result = $migration->processImport();
  }
}
```